# "npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-angular@latest" but nothing inside of node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm

I'm trying to include Azure AD for the login, but after running `npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-angular` aswell as `npm install @azure/msal-browser @azure/msal-angular@latest` no new entries in the node_modules folder can be seen. So when trying to import the modules

```
import { MsalModule } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
```

I get the warning `TS2307: Cannot find module '@azure/msal-browser' or its corresponding type declarations`

When running the commands it seems to install everything (I run it where the frontend is located, also tried running it in the folder where both frontend and backend are stored):

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@9.2.4 requires a peer of tslib@^1.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ant-design/icons-angular@9.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ant-design/icons-angular@9.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ant-design/icons-angular@9.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ant-design/icons-angular@9.0.1 requires a peer of tslib@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @rollup/plugin-commonjs@15.1.0 requires a peer of rollup@^2.22.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-zorro-antd@9.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/router@^9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @azure/msal-browser@2.20.0
+ @azure/msal-angular@2.0.6
updated 2 packages and audited 1717 packages in 11.119s
```

Comment: Are you running `npm install` in the location where your frontend is located? Do you see the packages get added to package.json? Are you getting error messages or warnings? Please provide us with additional (relevant) data to enable us to help you.

Comment: @rickvdbosch I have updated the question with more information

Comment: You have to run the commands where the file package.json is located. These commands will install the packages in local node_modules folder

Comment: @danvid that's what I did, go into frontend folder where package.json is located, run the command, it seemingly goes through but then nothing is in the node_modules folder and when trying to import it into app.module it gives me the above mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the only way `npm` will install something in a directory other than `./node_modules` is if [`global`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-config#global) is set. Run `npm config get global`. If it prints `true`, then this is your problem.

Find out where `global` is set with `npm config list`. Find `global = true` in the output, then start looking in the lines above it for a line that looks like `; "user" config from /Users/trott/.npmrc`. That line will tell you if the problem is in your user config, project config, or global config. You can try to use `npm config delete global` to remove the setting, but the `global` setting itself may be messing with that command. (I'm not actually sure of the cause. All I know is that I've experienced `npm config delete global` having no effect.) It might be best to run `npm config edit` to edit the config file to delete that line. (You can also use the path to open the file in the editor of your choice. Just be very careful not to make any changes other than removing the `global` setting line.)